# Copy constructor to create a one element Matrix of Vectors

Tags: matrix, julia, copy-constructor

In Julia, the following works:

```
julia> A = Matrix{Vector{Float64}}([[[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]] [[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]]])
5×2 Array{Array{Float64,1},2}:
[-3.0, 4.0]  [-3.0, 4.0]
[8.0]        [8.0]
[7.0, 8.0]   [7.0, 8.0]
[0.0, 9.0]   [0.0, 9.0]
[-1.0]       [-1.0]
```

That creates a `Matrix{Vector{Float64}}` with two identical columns.

However, using the same pattern to create the same object but with one column returns an error:

```
julia> A = Matrix{Vector{Float64}}([[[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]]])
```

How is this possible and how should I fix it?

My current workaround, which is unsatisfactory, from my point of view, because it uses `hcat`, is:

```
julia> A = hcat(Matrix{Vector{Float64}}(undef, 5, 0), [[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]])
5×1 Array{Array{Float64,1},2}:
[-3.0, 4.0]
[8.0]
[7.0, 8.0]
[0.0, 9.0]
[-1.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no need for putting the type declaration in front of your arrays. Just write

```
A = [[[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]] [[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]]]
```

This is an `Array{Array{Float64,1},2}`

If you do the same with your second try, you get something very different, though:

```
julia> [[[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]]]
1-element Array{Array{Array{Float64,1},1},1}
```

It's an array of an array of an array. Not what you wanted to start with.

Unfortunately for you, fixing this doesn't help. The reason is that you cannot simply convert a vector to a matrix, even when they are not nested:

```
julia> Matrix{Float64}([1.0,2.0,3.0])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Array{Float64,2}(::Array{Float64,1})
```

The error message is quite clear.

It's actually quite hard to create Nx1 matrices, but you can for example use reshape:

```
julia> reshape([[-3.0,4.0],[8.0],[7.0, 8.0],[0.0,9.0],[-1.0]], :, 1)
5×1 Array{Array{Float64,1},2}:
 [-3.0, 4.0]
 [8.0]      
 [7.0, 8.0] 
 [0.0, 9.0] 
 [-1.0]
```

Keep in mind that you very often don't need to pass your array literal into a constructor. Julia figures out the type by itself.